# blog which support to organize blog posts, categories as a tree

Tags: web-apps

Do you know any website or blog which could help me write blogs and organize blogs under tree directory? E.g I create some categories, make them in order and drag, drop or assign a blog post to each leaf category.

```
Category A
    |---Category B
    |     |---Category C
    |            |---Blog post #1
    |     |---Blog post #2
    |---Blog post #3
Category D
    |---Category E
    |     |---Blog post #4
    |---Blog post #5
```

I want to find blog post not only by tag but also by category that they belong to.

I have created a blog on wordpress.com but it couldn't help me to organize blog posts as a multi-node tree view.

Comment: Ah, with WordPress, have you tried using parent categories?

Comment: Ya, I have used parent categories and assigned blog post into a child category. But that not what I want. I want my home page look like something like this http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/dragdrop, and when visitor click on any blog post node. they will be directed to the blog post post.

Comment: Alright, I see what you're saying - WordPress may not have this feature right out of the box but you could accomplish this with a plugin, could you see if either (or both) of these work? The first one is called [WP-dTree](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-dtree-30/) and the second is [Tree Website Map](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-quick-organizational-tree/)

Comment: Thank Tom, because wordpress.com doesn't support adding other plugins except bullt-in plugins, so I have to hire a host, download the source on wordpress.org and these plugins, then upload to my host. This could be a hard work for me. So I refer a already deloyed blog platform (like wordpress.com) which have this feature